# Large Storage Solution

Tags: storage

We are a small bootstrapped ISP in a third world country where bandwidths are usually expensive and slow. We recently got a customer who need storage solution, of 10s of TB of mostly video files (its a tv station). The thing is I know my way around linux but I have never done anything like this before. We have a backblaze 3 storage pod casing which we are thinking of using as a storage server. The Server will be connected to customer directly so its not gonna go through the internet, because 100+mbps speed is unheard off in this part of the world.

I was thinking of using 4TB HDD all formatted with ext4 and using LVM to make them one large volume (50-70tb at least). So customer logs in to an FTP like client and dumps whatever files he/she wants. But the customer only sees a single volume, and we can add space as his requirements increases. Of course this is just on papers from preliminary research as i don't have prior experience with this kind of system. Also I have to take cost in to consideration so can't go for any proprietary solution.

My questions are:

- Is this the best way to handle this probably, are there equally good or better solutions out there?
- For large storage solutions (at least large for me) what are my cost effective options when it comes to dealing with data corruption and HD failure.

Would love to hear any other solutions and tips you guys might have. thanks!

Comment: What are your requirements for reliability and redundancy?

Comment: Our customers are non tech savvy, so there was no specific requirements, but obviously we would like to keep these things in mind, but not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately cant ask questions with this account at serverfault. I guess I should create another one?

Comment: Even if your customers are not asking for it, I would think it is common courtesy to have redundancy if you are selling a storage solution. Or at least inform your customers that "btw one disk failure and your data is gone, just a fyi"

Comment: absolutely we want to have some type of redundancy, its just that we don't know how to approach this problem in a cost-effective way, thats what I meant to say.

Comment: Have a look at ZFS - it is very scalable and configurable.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS might be a good option but there is no native bug-free solution for Linux, yet. I would recommend other operating systems in that case.

Today I would recommend Linux MD raid5 on enterprise disks or raid6 on consumer/desktop disks. I would not assign more than 6 disks to an array. LVM can then be used to tie the arrays to a logical volume suitable for ext4.

The ext4-filesystem is well tested and stable while XFS might be better for large file storage. The downside to XFS is that it is not possible to shrink an XFS filesystem. I would prefer ext4 because of it's more flexible nature.

Please also take into consideration that backups are still required even if you are storing your data on raid-arrays. The data can silently corrupt or be accidentally deleted.

In the end, everything depends on what the customer wants. Telling the customer the price of the service usually has an effect on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the answer that mingalsuo gave.  As he stated, it really comes down to the customer requirements. You don't say what, specifically, the customer will do with this data. Is it for archive only?  Will they be actively streaming the data? What is your budget for this project?  These types of answers will better determine the proposed solution.   Here are some options based on a great many assumptions. Maybe one of them will be a good fit for your project.

CAPACITY:
In this case, you are not that concerned about performance but more interested in capacity. In this case, the number of spindles don't really matter much. As Mingalsuo stated, put together a set of RAID-6 SATA arrays and use LVM to produce a large volume.

SMALL BUSINESS PERFORMANCE:
In this case, you need performance. The customer is going to store files but also requires the ability for a small number of simultaneous data streams.   Here you want as many spindles as possible. For streaming, it does little good to focus on the size of the controller cache.  Just focus on the number of spindles. You want as many as possible. Keep in mind that the time to rebuild a failed drive increases with the size of the drive. And, during a rebuild, your performance will suffer.  For these reasons I'd suggest smaller drives. Maybe 1TB drives at most. This will provide you with faster rebuild times and more spindles for streaming.

ENTERPRISE PERFORMANCE:
Here you need high performance - similar to that that an enterprise demands. You require many simultaneous data streams and performance is required. In this case, I would stay away from SATA drives and use 900G or 1.2TB SAS drives instead. I would also suggest that you consider abstracting the storage layer from the server layer. Create a Linux server and use iSCSI (or fibre) to connect to the storage device. This will allow you to load balance if possible, or at the very least make recovery from disaster easier.

NON TRADITIONAL SOLUTIONS:
You stated that the environment has few high-speed connections to the internet. Again, depending on the requirements, you still might consider cloud storage. Hear me out :)   Let's assume that the files will be uploaded today, used for the next week or month, and then rarely read. In this case, these files are sitting on (potentially) expensive disks for no reason except archive.   Wouldn't it be better to keep those active files on expensive (local) disk until they "retire" and then move them to less expensive disk?    There are solutions that do just that. One, for example, is called StorSimple. This is an appliance that contains SAS (and even flash) drives and uses cloud storage to automatically migrate "retired" data from the local storage to cloud storage. Because this data is retired it wouldn't matter if it took longer than normal to move it to the cloud. And, this appliance automatically pulls it back from the cloud to local storage when it is accessed.   This solution might be too expensive for your project but there are similar ones that you might find will work for you.    The added benefit of this is that your data is automatically backed up by the cloud provider and you have an unlimited supply of storage at your disposal.